# Is @Bean inside of @Component a singleton?

Tags: java, spring, singleton

I've read in some places that the difference between @Bean inside of @Component and @configuration, if that the latter provides a singleton bean while the former does not. Can anyone confirm if this is true or not?

Comment: Can you give a link and quotes?

Comment: Only `@Bean` in an `@Configuration` is a singleton, in an `@Component` it behaves as a prototype scoped bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `@Configuration` annotated classes those are processed in *full* mode mode, meaning the class is read using ASM, enhanced with CGLIB so that inter method calls will return the same instance.

Using `@Component` to declare beans those are process in *lite* mode. Not allowing for inter method references (you can do it but each call will create a new bean).

See als [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts) in the Spring Reference Guide which explains this in great(er) detail.

Comment: Even full mode beans are not necessarily singleton. The scope can be changed to `prototype` or other options so that multiple instances can be generated.

Answer (score -1):

Please specify the meaning of singleton in your question. Actually, in Spring world SINGLETON is the default bean scope and it doesn't matter where bean defined in Component or Configuration its scope will be SINGLETON, but can be overridden by supplying the scope attribute to @Bean annotation. Beans defined in Configuration has some constraints. More details you can find here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Comment: Beans defined in `@Configuration` behave different as beans defined in `@Component`. The latter runs in so called lite-mode.